# Regular expression and how to include a matching string but exclude matching string ending with an underscore?

Tags: regex

I have tried so many ways to solve this in perl/sed and read up quite a bit about negative lookaheads etc but still the match doesn't work.
I have lines such as :-

```
for (vector<some__header>::const_iterator header = some__header_->begin(); header != some__header_->end(); ++header)
```

and

```
for (vector<some__trailer>::const_iterator header = some__trailer_->begin(); header != some__trailer_->end(); ++header)
```

I want to replace text matching **some`__`value** with **other`__`value** but not any text which matches **some`__`value_**

So, if I was to replace **some** with **other** for the first line, I'd get :-

```
for (vector<other__header>::const_iterator header = some__header_->begin(); header != some__header_->end(); ++header)
```

Obviously, something like (in perl) :-

```
(some)__([a-zA-Z]*)(?!_)
```

is not working as it will match **some__heade** as well.
What's the magic regex part I'm missing?

Comment: AFAIK sed doesn't support look aheads :(

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was testing out in perl which I can also get away with. Updating main entry.

Comment: Try using start/end of words: \< and \>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and a possesive quantifier for alphas:

```
perl -pe 's/some(__(?>[[:alpha:]]*))(?!_)/other$1/g' infile
```

With an example line of:

```
for (vector<some__header>::const_iterator header = some__header_->begin(); header != some__header->end(); ++header)  some__header_
```

It yields:

```
for (vector<other__header>::const_iterator header = some__header_->begin(); header != other__header->end(); ++header)  some__header_
```

Comment: Spoilt for choice now as @hwnd has also supplied a working version using sed.

Comment: Except his answer has disappeared? sed -re 's/some(_+[^_]+?)\b/other\1/g'

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
sed 's/some__header[^_]/other__value/g' filename
```

Also,

```
sed 's/some__[^_]*[^_]/other__value/g' filename
```

---

If only `some` is to be replaced with `other`, say:

```
sed 's/some__\([^_]*\)[^_]/other__\1/g' filename
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, `[^_]` matches last alphabetic character when the word end with `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the trailing non-underscore too:

```
sed 's/some\(__[a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z_]\)/other\2/g'
```

The key is the negated character class can't just be `[^_]` because that allows the last letter of the name to be the non-underscore.

Also note the slight rearrangement to simplify things

Comment: In this case the engine will backtrack to make `[^_]` match an alphabetic letter. It will match every words.

Comment: Still too greedy.  `echo "for (vector<some__header>::const_iterator header = some__header_->begin(); header != some__header_->end(); ++header)"|sed 's/\(some\)\(__[a-zA-Z]*[^_]\)/other\2/g'`  will still end up giving   `for (vector<other__header>::const_iterator header = other__header_->begin(); header != other__header_->end();` ++header)